# Django: CSRF token missing or incorrect. / avoid {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django

I'm following the Django guide on Show me to do. But I have a  question:

If I just copy his code I gen an

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I've solved that problem by adding

```py
context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

to all "my" return render_to_response
and by adding the tag {% csrf_token %} to the form I'm calling.

Here it comes the question: Can I in any way set this up to be invoked "behind the sceenes" or do I have to add this to all my forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `render(request, template, context)` rather than `render_to_response`. The `render` shortcut uses a RequestContext automatically.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is an important security concept AFAIK.

You either have to set `csrf_token` [which would set a hidden post parameter] to all forms which uses post, put or delete request or You can use `X-CSRFToken` header as well. You can use `render` shortcut rather than `render_to_response` to include `RequestContext` by default. See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

There is a way to completely avoid CSRF checks by removing `middleware` or using a `decorator`
. But I would recommend against this.

Comment: Thankyou. But with the example you link to I still have to do someting in each call

Isn't it posible do define my own render_to_response wich just add context_instance=RequestContext(request) the tha call ?

Comment: I donot think there is backend solution for this as it is dependent on client side as well AFAIK. CSRF checks are handled with `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` see if you can extend this to work in your way.